# datetime to float not include milliseconds

Tags: python, datetime

Below code didn't convert milliseconds to float. what's the right way to do it?

```
import datetime

def date2float(datestr):
    format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"
    dateobj = datetime.datetime.strptime(datestr, format)
    print dateobj
    dtfloat = mktime(dateobj.timetuple())
    print dtfloat
    return dtfloat

date2float("2015-03-08 10:34:01.2")
date2float("2015-03-08 10:34:01.4")
```

Current output is:

```
2015-03-08 10:34:01.200000
1425828841.0
2015-03-08 10:34:01.400000
1425828841.0
```

Obviously, the 0.2 and 0.4 has been lost.

Comment: what is the input timezone?

Comment: It should be the default one but in my case, I didn't care about it.

Comment: why do you care about milliseconds if you don't care about being wrong by hours if you use a wrong timezone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mktime does not handle fractional seconds. You can add the microseconds by hand:

```
def date2float(datestr):
    format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"
    dateobj = datetime.datetime.strptime(datestr, format)
    dtfloat = mktime(dateobj.timetuple())
    dtfloat += dateobj.microsecond / 1000000.0
    return dtfloat
```

---

In Python 3.3+:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()
1425826728.740325
```

Comment: `mktime()` (and `timestamp()` that uses it internally) may fail during DST transitions and for past/future dates if your local timezone may have different utc offsets at different times (many timezones do). Use the explicit `pytz` timezone corresponding to your local timezone to avoid the issues.